# how to load gzip file?

Tags: javascript, gzip, web-optimization

I am toally new on this, so I compress all my js files to one gzip, and then what do I do ? do I just simply change my code to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='sample.js.gz'></script>
```

as I used to load those js files ?
or do I need to uncompress it ?

Comment: you shouldn't do this. you should let the server and the web browser negotiate this.

Comment: Can you give more details on this please

Comment: web servers can be configured to compress http traffic. then the web browser is responsible for deflatting it.

Comment: I am not sure about the flow..so you basically make an ajax call when the page onload and then get back those js file and then include them ?

Comment: im saying you shouldn't gzip them at all.

Comment: Why ? I thought that's how you optimize the site speed by compression them to gzip, and Google Speed (add-on for chrome) also gives me that feedback as well.

Comment: I have to ask why not as well, some good data on the pros and cons would be very helpful

Comment: A web server, if properly configured, and if the browser agree, will gzip the content. That's the standard and most efficient way. Don't go in the way of this process.

Comment: what that Google Speed meant is to configure the web server to use gzip compression for transmitting files, the compression is invisible to the HTML file, so you just write the code as usual